# Requesting data from a React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Suppose I have a node.js server running on `localhost:2000`, this routes GET requests and calls an external API to populate responses.

Now, I also have a react.js front end running on `localhost:3000`, which queries the node server at `localhost:2000` to get responses using axios.

What is the point of doing so? If I'm already using axios in my react app why can't I just directly call the external API from it? Is this simply a design decision? Such that there is server-client separation and cleaner code or does it serve a higher purpose?

PS. For the sake of clarity - This method is no different from using a proxy for the react app. Correct? i.e. configuring a proxy in the `package.json` and have the react app simply `fetch` endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is the frontend part of your app, and the node.js server is the backend. Everything in the frontend part of your app will be exposed to the client, but the server side will be hidden to them, whatever you do in the server will be kept secure (depending on the security measures you take).

If you just want to access a third party API and have no security reasons of not doing so (a simple call to a third party service that gives you the official time of your country for example), you can do it so directly from your React app. You can also redirect it using your server in node as well (calling your server first, and then calling the API from your server). The second option here seems like a long route for something simple, but in some cases it might be helpful to do so, for example if you are calling your API with some security credentials and you want to configure them in your server, again for security, or if you don't want to expose the logic of calling that external API. Usually, getting information from a database is done in the server side, not in the frontend side, because you don't want to expose your db's server, credentials, etc.

This can be a design decision, in which you get the logic of calling an external API in the server side for security reasons. If you manage this information in React (meaning frontend) you will expose much of this information to the client (everything in the frontend will be loaded to the browser at some point).

Keep simple calls in your React app, and important security calls in your server side.